# arithmetics on the elements of list of tuples and detecting the required combinations as pairs

Tags: python, linux, list, tuples

Here in the input and statement of its explanatioon

```
a= [( 0.1, 0.2, 0.3), (0.2, 0.8, 0.9, 4.5), ( 0.11, 0.22, 0.33), (0.2, 0.46, 0.475, 1.8, 1.95)]
```

Each element of the tuple represents a length of chord. Like the first tuple consists of 3 chords representing a triangle with length of sides 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3. The second one is a rectangle and so on. In each tuple there can be a variable number of elements. Like in the first tuple there are 3 element, in the second there are 4 element, in the third there are again 3 elements while in the fourth there are 5 elements. So it can be variable too.

Now comes the task.

In SOME tuples the length of its one of the elements CAN BE half or double of the length of element of another tuple. In that case the ID of the (couple) tuples needs to be output and NOT the length it self. The ID of tuple would be helpful to identify if it was the first tuple, the second or another. The ID of the element is not required just the ID of the tuples.

Like for the given case the result would be

```
1 2   because 0.1 exists in tuple 1 and 0.2 exists in tuple 2
1 4   because 0.1 exists in tuple 1 and 0.2 exists in tuple 4
2 4   because 0.9 exists in tuple 2 and 1.8 exists in tuple 4
```

Please note that

```
0.1 and 0.2 exist in tuple 1
```

but it would not be output as 1 1 because it is in the same tuple. This should not excluded if the half or double length exists in the same tuple.
is it possible to apply a barrier of +-5% of the length, just to consider the numerical and round-off error?

I just learnt concatenated use of tuple so a try was

```
couples = []
for lengths in a:
 for length in lengths:
  if [length==i*2 for i in tup) for tup in b)]:
   couples.append(length,i)
  elif [length==i*0.5 for i in tup) for tup in b)]:
   couples.append(length,tup)
```

but I am unaware of its proper use for comparison.

Comment: to those it is still not clear, I have added the answer myself. The only point is, it is written is 20 lines. Any expert could have suggested that in smaller number of lines or atleast a direction as done by @rrauenza.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution works like following. Although it is not an elegant way but from the scratch and simple commands it would look like below

```
a= [( 0.1, 0.2, 0.3), (0.2, 0.8, 0.9, 4.5), ( 0.11, 0.22, 0.33), (0.2, 0.46, 0.475, 1.8, 1.95)]

couples = []              # define an empty list                                                      
totalTupleIDs= len(a) # get the length of list of tuples to loop over tuples

for i in range(totalTupleIDs):  # Start the loop over tuples
 totalElementsInTuple=len(a[i]) # get the length of tuple to loop over its elements
 for j in range(totalElementsInTuple): # start loop over elements of tuples
  currentElement1= a[i][j]   # get the current element inside tuple
  print currentElement1
  for k in range(totalTupleIDs):  # Start the second loop for comparison purpose over the same list of tuples!
   print a[k]
   totalElementsInTuple=len(a[k])
   print totalElementsInTuple
   for l in range(totalElementsInTuple): #start the second loop for comparison over the elements of tuples
    currentElement2= a[k][l]
    print currentElement2
    if currentElement1==currentElement2: # compare the elements
     if i==k:  # if the IDs of tuples are same, its a redundant result, leave!
      print "Redundant"
     else:
      print " Similar at %d  %d "  % (i , k) # if there is no self comparison , append the result 
      couples.append((i, k))  
print couples # output and compare the result
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very hard to follow, but I can see some of your trouble in your `if` statement.  Here are a couple of examples based on what I understand your problem to be.  Please clarify your problem in your question if this is not enough help.

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                               

a = [( 1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3, 6, 4.5), ( 0, 0, 0), (4, 1.1, 99)]                   

couples = []                                                                    

for lengths in a:                                                               
    for length in lengths:                                 
        if length*2 in lengths:                                         
            couples.append((length, length*2))                                
        elif length*0.5 in lengths:                                       
            couples.append((length, length*0.5))                                

print couples
```

Or

```
couples = []                                                                    

for lengths in a:                                                               
    for length in lengths:                                                      
        for f in filter(lambda v: length * 2 == v, lengths):                    
            couples.append((f, length * 2))                                     
        for f in filter(lambda v: length * 0.5 == v, lengths):                  
            couples.append((f, length * 0.5))                                   

print couples
```

The first example uses `in` to test whether an element is in a `list` or not without needing to explicitly loop over the values.  This only allows you to check for explicit values.

The second example uses a `lambda` function to filter the lengths according to some rule, which is more flexible.  If you wanted to permit 5% approximations you would modify the expression `lambda v: length * 2 == v`.

Comment: I have explained the problem again and changed the data too for more clarity about the lengths. Your code gives the output in the form of lengths and make their couples. I need the IDs of the tuples as couples which fulfil the condition.  thanks for your time.